# Cannot receive data from GPS SD Shield V2-B

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, softwareserial, gps

I am attempting to receive GPS data from a GPS SD Shield V2-B purchased from maplin. I have attempted the very simple sketch they provide on their website linksprite.com.
I have also tried following a tutorial found here: http://tronixstuff.com/2014/01/15/tutorial-arduino-mediatek-3329-gps/. 
This is the code i am using:

```
    // Example 19.1

    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial GPS(2,3); // configure software serial port - 

    void setup()
    {
      GPS.begin(9600);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
    }
    void loop()
    {
      byte a;
        if (GPS.available() > 0 )
      {
        a = GPS.read(); // get the byte of data from the GPS
        Serial.write(a);
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(13,LOW);
        delay(1000);
      }
    }
```

I am using an Arduino 101. The jumpers on the GPS shield are set up as follows:[image]

I have attempted using both power simply from my Mac and an external 9V battery connected to the Arduino.
The 'blink' has been added the sketch to test whether data was being received but there was a problem with the serial monitor. This is not the case because the blink did not occur. It however did occur when moved outside of the if statement as you would expect.
Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like hardware, if you are using an existing sketch and shield. Did you solder the pins onto the shield, or just push them in?

Comment: The shield came pre-assembled so didn't require any soldering. The jumpers used are removable and are just pushed on

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the jumps as per the instructions that came with the shield ...
PAGE4 : short jumpers TX and MRX .... and RX and MTX